# How can I get the installation log of an MSI which is being deployed via a group policy?

Tags: windows, group-policy, msi

I have an MSI for a driver which I want to deploy via a group policy.

I have a problem with it deploying on 64bit machines and want to log what is happening.  The installation works fine as an administrator account, however for a large scale deployment it is not feasible to use the administrator account to deploy this driver.

How can I get the MSI's installation log file for when its being called by the SYSTEM account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually trigger the installation as SYSTEM. Grab a copy of psexec and run `psexec -s cmd` and you will have an interactive command prompt as system. From there you can run `msiexec /i yourMSI.msi /q` and see all of the console output as well as the local event log.